# using custom database with roles in identity server 4

Tags: identityserver3, identityserver4

I am working on an application where I need to setup identity server 4. I have an api as resource. and a web forms application as client.I have few roles like teachers, students, parents in my database. How can I use this custom database and perform authentication and authorization without using identity?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40601913/using-aspnet-identity-with-custom-tables) I get a better idea of what you want.

I think one solution for what you want would be to setup identityserver4 in a seperate project with its own seperate database. I noticed the tag identityserver3, but I think it is quite safe to go for identityserver4. It shouldn't make a difference for the client/user since they are conceptually compatible.

1) Give your application a client/secret (which you configure in identityserver) in order to identify your application and grant access to the resource api. Here is some information: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/dev/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html

You'll only need to configure one client to protect your resource from the outside. The only way to access the resource api is through your application, since your application is making the actual calls. This is also the drawback, you cannot expose the token to the outside world.

Since your client isn't the actual user, you'll need to identify the user. You can use any mechanism based on your current model as you like. A simple user/pass (with or without asp.net identity) could be enough to determine the roles. But please keep in mind that your application has full access to the resource api.

2) However, since identityserver is available, why not use it? Why don't you want to use the identitymodel? I think you should consider to seperate the identity information and your datamodel. Your datamodel shouldn't be aware of the security. And the security has nothing to do with your datamodel.

When you create a seperate database for identityserver you have one place to configure the identity users. All you need is a reference (sub) to the user in the datamodel. http://docs.identityserver.io/en/dev/quickstarts/2_resource_owner_passwords.html

Add claims or roles and everything is in place and you'll see there is no need to keep identity data in your custom database. The structure of your custom database stays intact, including the user table but without the identity data.

I think this is a safer solution and considering the good documentation and sample projects it may even turn out to be a quicker solution.